# how to only send line notify when conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('bd1')
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var column = data.map(function (row) {
    return row[6];
  });

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var cellAArray = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cellF = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    if (cellF == "HBD") {
      var cellA = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      cellAArray.push(cellA);
    } else {

      Logger.log("none")
    }

  }{

    var formattedCellAArray = cellAArray.join(String.fromCharCode(10));
    {
      var lineNotifyToken = "yE4gPgRSDFjtz9FKD0ZZpveXsZryaTaYsIBCYT4CXgr";
      var message = "\n" + "\n" + " \uD83C\uDF89 \u2764 สุขสันต์วันเกิด (HAPPY BIRTHDAY) \u2764 \uD83C\uDF89" + "\n" + "\n" + "\uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 \uD83C\uDF82 " + "\n" + "\n" + formattedCellAArray + "\n";

      var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://scontent.fvte5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/378147329_154542441038014_4154070742522105587_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s960x960&_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=49d041&_nc_eui2=AeHaXRlZz19_Utdp-2Z3bDzv5HAyZkSRrU3kcDJmRJGtTb3YGhCU4ifb5MqvV_4KX7RBDdBCKtmFm6VJkjXhI7sQ&_nc_ohc=Zn5bk_5fdsUAX86l0CH&_nc_ht=scontent.fvte5-1.fna&oh=00_AfDrOXS_f9m6MEvuK99dZThp4KkIZqqDpos4rZcxxNJFOQ&oe=65167548").getBlob();

    }
  }
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": {
      "message": message,
      "imageFile": image
    },
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + lineNotifyToken
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", options);

}

//var formattedCellAArray1 = cellAArray.map(cell => cell + " \uD83D\uDE00"); //add emoji after every cell but fail
//var stickerPackageId = "1";
//var stickerId = "1";    // add sticker   https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/sticker-list/#sticker-definitions
```

I try to send happy birthday wish and picture when it's their birthday by setting trigger in app script to check the condition, but it keeps sending me notification everyday with "message" even when it's nobody's birthday what should I do?

Comment: What's with all those unneeded `{}` blocks? Have you removed some code? And I see no condition for checking if there is a birthday or not, so of course the final `fetch` is always done ...